# CakePHP 3, in Entity, how to only send data modified to view?

Tags: cakephp, entity, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm currently using entity to send data modified at Entity to view.
such as

```
 protected function _getType($type){
    if($type == 'L'){
        return 'LinkedIn';
    }elseif($type == 'F'){
        return 'Facebook';
    }else{
        return 'Email';
    }
}
```

The problem is when i get data to store in database, the "type" value "L" was modified to "LinkedIn" and saved it as "LinkedIn".

Is there any other way to only show the data modified not save it modified?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply create a virtual property, ie choose a name that doesn't match an existing field, like

```
protected function _getExpandedType()
{
    switch($this->get('type')) {
        case 'L':
            return 'LinkedIn';
        case 'F':
            return 'Facebook';
    }
    return 'Email';
}
```

```
<?= $entity->expanded_type ?>
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Creating Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6856**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6698**